# Model for panel data with aggregate metrics over time

Tags: regression, panel-data

I have data of individuals giving scores with millions of observations on thousands of products. The individual scores are ordered at the product level, representing a sequence starting from 1 to the maximum number of scores that product received.
By now I aggregate products by the first n scores they receive, creating average score, standard deviation etc.
My goal is to create a regression model that tests how the first n scores of an item affect the average score of the next n scores and so on, using the aggregated metrics (mean, sd, ...) of items.

I thought about using a lagged regression with the average score of the next n score as the dependent variable and (mean, sd, ...) of the previous n score with a lag of n as independent variables.
Another model I found would be a rolling regression.

Is this an appropriate approach or are there models better suited for the goal I am pursuing?